# tSQLt - Install failed

Tags: tsqlt

I have downloaded the tSQLt and execute the PrepareServer.sql and received the error message below:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AuditLogDDLEvents, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 189]
Invalid object name 'AuditLogDDL'.
```

Please help to resolve the issue.
Thank everyone!

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AuditLogDDLEvents, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 189]
Invalid object name 'AuditLogDDL'.
```

Answer (score 1):

AuditLogDDL is not part of tSQLt. You likely have a DDL trigger in master that is attempting to call that procedure.

Note: Please be sure to install tSQLt in a test or development environment. Never install tSQLt in production.

Comment: Woh, Perfect, Thank you so much, Sebastian Meine!

Comment: Glad I could help, @user3624829. Would you mind marking my answer as accepted, please.